# How to layout Array of buttons to fit in any screen size

Tags: android

I have created an array of buttons for my app. Now I am not able to manage the layout of these array of buttons. As a result of this, whenever I add image or change width of the buttons it's going out of the horizontal screen of the device. So is there any way to manage these Array of buttons so that they can fit in any screen size.
Here is my code:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liVLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liVLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/liVLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="All Contacts" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="#808080">
    </TextView> 
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
public class CalenderForm extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    createCalender();
}
public void createCalender()
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    (
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );  
    LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
    Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7]; 
    int count=43;
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) 
    {
        if(count%7==1)
        {
            rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,p);
            count=count-7;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon); 
            rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j], p);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Snapshot before inserting image:

[image]

Snapshot before inserting image:

[image]

Comment: 1. Try reducing the spacing between the buttons.  2. Try using relative layout..

Comment: when i used relative layout nothing only one button is displayed..

Comment: You can add any number of buttons you want in relative layout.. may be you have some other issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace this code.use weightsum property of linear and layout_weight of buttons.

```
package com.android.manager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        createCalender();
    }
    public void createCalender()
    {  
        LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
        LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
        Button[][] buttons = new Button[6][7]; 
        int count=43;
        **LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);**

        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) 
        {
            if(count%7==1)
            {
                rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                **rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);**
                **layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);**
                count=count-7;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
                **rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],param);**
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks its working fine..one more thing it will adjust automatically for each screen size..or we have to do seperate thing for that

Comment: hi hitendra..one question..when i set background image for each button than is become inactive thats menas i am not able to click button..why this happened..

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I just want to help you out. If you're building a calendar app, creating lots of buttons really isn't the way to go:

1. You will have problems on different ROMs because of skins, etc.
2. You will not have full control over the layout (again because of the skins)
3. You will run into spacing issues
4. You will allocate a lot of memory (lots of `Button` objects, etc.) which will cause your app to be slow.

What I recommend is implementing your own custom [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). I recently worked on a calendar app myself and tried using a `GridView` for the month, and that really didn't work out well (although it looked like it would), so I ultimately created my own `View`, which worked out perfect.

What I found very useful was Android's default, open source [Calendar](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=tree) app. You'll find source code in there for both a month view and a day / week view (with an hour scale, etc.).

Comment: yeh..what you say is upto point but my assignment is to create your own cuctom calendar using Array of buttons..so please give me some suggestion regarding this

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `TableLayout` and set the columns wrappable:

Found a nice tutorial with examples -> [Android TableLayout Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=307)

> To make a column wrappable (to reduce it’s width and wrap it’s content if other columns in the table are taking too much space and pushing some columns off the screen),  use setColumnShrinkable to mark it shrinkable.

sounds promising

Comment: +1 just for the link alone.  It's full of great explanations of those damn barely-intelligible TableLayout terms.